# Hyperledger fabric and Ethereum integration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum, smartcontracts

We were planning to build a blockchain based on below logic, but understand due to the private data(a portion of our data is private while some data is public), it is not possible on Ethereum. Would the same design / implementation be possible using Hyperledger Fabric?

Our current design : Blockchain on ethereum but keeping the data related to blocks in some distributed file storage system like IPFS or Storj and storing the hash of data in blocks. But we need our data to be private / shared, so to achieve that we are thinking of using some Key Management Service like NuCypher KMS. But we will have smart contracts on ethereum which can access the data and perform some operations.

We understand that the above logic is unable due to the private nature of data. Is there anyway to establish communication between Hyperledger fabric data and Ethereum smart contract?

Answer (score -1):

It is quite possible to make a part of the transaction data private and other part of the transaction data private in Ethereum using various smart contract obfuscation techniques. One such technique is known as Zero Knowledge Proof which can be implemented in Ethereum at a Smart Contract level using Aztech Protocol. It is possible to implement Zero Knowledge Proofs in Ethereum in a further extended way using ZoKrates libraries which implements libsnarks. In Hyperledger Fabric, from version 1.2 onwards there is a feature known as 'Side DB' which helps us to have private transaction between two peers.

As you have mentioned, using NuCypher platform with homomorphic encryption and proxy re-encryption is always a good idea. We may need to push data from NuCypher into a Smart Contract through Web3.js or by some other easier approach.

With regard to your third question, yes, it is possible to integrated Ethereum and Hyperledger Fabric from Hyperledger 1.4 easily. It has integrated Hyperledger Burrow which makes compiling and deploying Ethereum Smart Contracts on Hyperledger Fabric easier. However I am not sure how much it will help your purpose.

Thinking again, I believe offline encryption using NuCypher / Decentralised Oracles and then invoking Smart Contracts with Meta Data from encrypted data vault looks like a good design choice. I feel Hyperledger Fabric may be an overkill for implementing an offline encryption vault.